# Does the adverb "quitely" exist?

Tags: vocabulary, adverbs

I was surprised not to find the adverb "quitely" in my dictionary whereas I am pretty sure that I saw it several times. Does it exist or is it a (common?) mistake?

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of QUIETLY

Comment: Or, you may have seen typos where the writer **meant** "quietly".

Comment: It is not a typo, it is really "quitely".

Comment: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=define+%22quitely%22+-quietly

Comment: _Quite_ is already an adverb in itself. There is no need to create an adverb from it by adding _-ly_, and such an adverb does not exist in any variant of English I've ever been exposed to. From your phrasing and profile, I'm guessing you are a non-native speaker from France, in which case I wonder if perhaps you've seen other non-native speakers use _quitely_, as a type of hypercorrect form; it is similar to saying _vitement_ or _malment_ in French.

Comment: @Janus Apparently _quitely_ is obsolete. Your suggestion about attempts to unflatten 'quite' being a hypercorrection make sense.

Comment: Thusly have I myself oftenly wondered whether these redundantly replicative adadverbials, nowly so seldomly seen, won’t become more common tomorrowly.

Comment: @tchrist- I quite like *oftenly*

Answer (score 4):

It exits but is quite obsolete:

[Quitely](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quitely)

> - entirely, quite.

Origin:

> - Middle English, from quit, quite, adjective, free + -ly

[Ngram- quitely](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quitely&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquitely%3B%2Cc0).

Source:www.merriam-webster.com

---

Just to add another source - here's OED1 - adverb of Quit - Obs.

[image: OED1 quitely]

Comment: This [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quitely%2Cquietly%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquitely%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquietly%3B%2Cc0) tells a different story. Please look at the cited examples too

Comment: [There is no surer sign of damnation, than for a man to die quitely after a sinful life](http://books.google.it/books?id=KAADAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA1-PA182&dq=%22quitely%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BsUKVObfKIWhO_CKgJgE&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22quitely%22&f=false) How does that make any sense *unless* it means to die quietly, in silence.

Comment: Could that be a typo? Quietly vs quitely

Comment: Maybe it's a spelling variation. Look at the other examples on the Ngram chart.

Comment: Yeah..intresting..probably also some misunderstanding on the meaning of the two terms.

Comment: ........Verily.